# Cannot find control with name: accept

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add the accept term and condition control as form control. Below is the codes I have. But it runs into error "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'accept'". accept is the form control name.

**product.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm">
    <div class="container-fluid" formArrayName="product">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>product</th>
                    <th>amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of productForm.get('products')?.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td>
                        <select id="name" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
                            <option *ngFor='let productOpt of productOpts'
                                    [value]="productOpt.id">{{productOpt.value}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="amount" class="form-control" formControlName="amount" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="accept" formControlName="accept"  />
            <label class="form-check-label">I accept the terms and conditions</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**product.component.ts**

```
constructor(
    private readonly fb: FormBuilder
) {
    this.productForm =
        this.fb.group({
            product: this.fb.array([
                this.createProductRow(),
                this.createProductRow()
            ]),
            accept: [false, [Validators.required]]
        });

}

createProductRow() {
    return this.fb.group({
        name: [''],
        amount: ['']
    });
}
```

Comment: has you any "variable" or "ViewChild" with the same name `accept`? Your code looks like fine. Well, I like create the form in the ngOnInit, but I think the problem.BTW, you should use `Validators.CheckboxRequiredValidator` for the checkbox

Comment: @Eliseo I don't have variable or ViewChild with the same name accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class, you create the FormGroup with the `product` property (in singular), while in your template, you use `products` (plural).

Also, for better debugging purposes and code readability, I would suggest that you moved the line of code `productForm.get('product')?.controls` to a getter in your class instead of handling that logic directly in your template, like so:

```
get productControls() {
    const controls = this.productForm.get('product') as FormArray;
    return controls.controls;
}
```

And in the template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of productControls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

This also get in the way of the Angular compiler sometimes.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-crukuj?file=src/index.html)

Comment: Hmm. Still the same after trying.

Comment: With both changes? I tried on a stackblitz and it works. Going to add the link to the answer.